# Understanding merge summary stats, clarification needed

Tags: git

Once i merged my code between branches, i got the following summary statistics line:

```
 97 files changed, 5053 insertions(+), 5814 deletions(-)
```

What's the most accurate way to understand this? Does this include blank lines? If so, is it possible to get stat information excluding them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the insertions and deletions do include blank lines.

You can influence these counts by:

- Adding a new line (this increases the insertions count)
- Removing a line (this increases the deletions count)
- Changing a line (this increases the deletions and insertions count)

Breaking down the message, it reads:

`97 files changed`: There were 97 files modified.

`5053 insertions(+)`: There were 5053 lines added (or modified).

`5814 deletions(-)`: There were 5814 lines removed (or modified).

Comment: Please confirm that insertions and deletions are separately counted. In other words, a total of 5053+5814 lines were changes in this example. Is this correct?

Comment: Git double counts modifications.  Changing a single line will result 1 deletion for removing the old version of the line and 1 insertion for adding the new line.